# separar cadena para un spinner

Tags: java, android, string, split

Quiero separar esta cadena para un spinner.

Aca recibo mi JSON lo recorro para solo obtener lo que deseo.

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("payment_methods");

ArrayList<String> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    try {
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //Aquí se obtiene el dato y es guardado en una lista
        Lista.add(json.get("title").toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

ctOnGo.setMetodosPagos(Lista.toString());
```

> ctOnGo.setMetodosPagos(Lista.toString()); Esto es para guardar lo que me extraje del JSON

El spinner esta aca

```
//Spinner
SpinnerMethod = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_methodopago);
String[] method = {ctPagar.getMetodosPagos()};
ctPagar.getMetodosPagos().split("\\|");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, method);
SpinnerMethod.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Ahora quiero que esto que guarde **{ctPagar.getMetodosPagos()};** se vea asi:

> Check / Money order
>
> PayPal
>
> Pago en la entrega
>
> Pago estandar

Pero me sale es en cadena: **Check / Money order, PayPal, Pago en la entrega, Pago estandar**

Answer (score 0):

Si en la cadena original tienes:

> Check / Money order, PayPal, Pago en la entrega, Pago estandar

Usa este split para obtener los valores:

```
ctPagar.getMetodosPagos().split(",");
```

ahora en cada elemento del array debes agregar nueva linea y retorno de carro `"\n\r"`, esto supongo lo harías dentro del método `getMetodosPagos()`, ejemplo:

```
   String[] palabras = s.split(",");
   for(int i = 0 ; i< palabras.length ; i++ ){
       palabras[i] = palabras[i] + "\n\r";     
   }
```